# limit substitution property

Tags: real-analysis

How do you prove the following?

Suppose $y=f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = b$

If

1) $g$ is continuous at $b$

or

2) $f(x) \neq b$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)$ exist
then 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = \lim_{y\to b}g(y)
$$

---

I got the first condition its pretty straightforward:

Since $|f(x)-b|< \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon$, $|x-a| < \delta$ can be satisfied and $g$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ there exist $\varepsilon$ such that $|g(f(x)-g(b)|< \varepsilon$2 is satisfied. $\varepsilon$ can always be chosen, and thus $\delta$, which gives our result for the first condition.

Im having problems with the second condition though.

Comment: Zhanfeng, I formatted your question using a web-variant of LaTeX. Please make sure I didn't change the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c = \lim_{y\to b} g(y)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since the limit exists, there is some $\delta$ such that $0<|y-b|<\delta \Rightarrow |g(y)-c| < \epsilon.$

Since $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = b$, there is some $\delta_2$ such that

$$0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow 0 < |f(x)-b| < \delta \Rightarrow |g(f(x))-c| < \epsilon,$$
and therefore $\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x)) = c.$

The inequality $0 < |f(x)-b|$ follows from $f(x) \neq b$.

Comment: Could you clarify why the inequality 0<|f(x)−b|  is necessary for the second condition, but not the first? I.e what is the difference  between proofs for the first and second conditions?

Comment: $|g(y)-c|<\epsilon$ only if $0<|y-b|<\delta$. The definition of the limit of $g(y)$ says nothing if $0=|y-b|$, and indeed perhaps $g(b) \neq c$.

Comment: Why is this not required for the first condition?

Comment: If $g$ is continuous, $\lim_{y\to b} g(y) = g(b)$ (by definition of continuity, really) so there's no worry about the case $y=b$.